# Custom location for .pypirc file

Tags: python, jenkins, setuptools, pypi

Does `setuptools` allow for the `.pypirc` file to be specified in a custom location rather than `$HOME/.pypirc`? I'm setting up a jenkins job to publish to an internal repository, and want the `.pypirc` file to be inside the job's workspace.

Comment: If you run it in docker, it would make it a whole lot easier, because you can set the `HOME` var for the container and mount a custom `/pypirc`

Answer (score 11):

This is doable by overloading the default command classes used for communication with the PyPI or your custom repository server. This can be done in your `setup.py` script. Let the code do the talk first:

```python
# this is your project's setup.py script

import os
from distutils.command.register import register as register_orig
from distutils.command.upload import upload as upload_orig

from setuptools import setup


class register(register_orig):

    def _get_rc_file(self):
        return os.path.join('.', '.pypirc')

class upload(upload_orig):

    def _get_rc_file(self):
        return os.path.join('.', '.pypirc')

setup(
    name='myproj',
    ...
    cmdclass={
        'register': register,
        'upload': upload,
    }
)
```

Now, if you call e.g.

```
$ python setup.py sdist register upload
```

the server credentials will be taken from `.pypirc` in the project directory instead of the default `~/.pypirc` one.

So basically, all you need to do is to replace the `register` and `upload` commands with your own implementations. These implementations redefine the `_get_rc_file` method with your own logic. After that, don't forget to adjust the `cmdclass` argument in your `setup` function so your own command classes are used instead of the standard ones.

Of course, as both classes redefine the same method, you could prettify the code by e.g. writing a mixin class and reusing it etc etc. Also, if you are uploading the sphinx docs to PyPI via `upload_docs` command, you have to overload it the same way. Anyway, you should get the basic idea of command overloading from the snippet above.

Comment: I know that this answer is old but I am wondering is it `cmdlcass` as is shown in the code snippet or `cmd_class` as is mentioned in the text following the snippet?

Comment: @andrew-falanga that's `cmdclass` :-) Good catch!

Comment: Upvoted.  Thanks for clarifying the object name.  :-)  I just finished implementing this and it works great in our automated build system.

Answer (score 10):

You might want to check out [twine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine). This tool allows you to specify a custom `.pypirc` file via the option `--config-file`

Answer (score 3):

In the last version of `setuptools` (version 29.0.1), the `.pypirc` file is loaded from the `$HOME` directory (or `%USERPROFILE%` on Windows).

This is done in the `setuptools.package_index.PyPIConfig` class. See the [source code](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/setuptools/package_index.py#L997) on GitHub:

```
class PyPIConfig(configparser.RawConfigParser):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Load from ~/.pypirc
        """
        defaults = dict.fromkeys(['username', 'password', 'repository'], '')
        configparser.RawConfigParser.__init__(self, defaults)

        rc = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.pypirc')
        if os.path.exists(rc):
            self.read(rc)
```

So, the only solution I see is to temporary redefine the `HOME` environment variable before running the Jenkins job.