# PyPi AssertionError: unsupported schema

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pypi

I'm trying to upload my package to PyPi and came up with this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    author_email= #my email,
  File "C:\Programming\Python\Anaconda\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Programming\Python\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Programming\Python\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Programming\Python\Anaconda\lib\distutils\command\upload.py", line 63, in run
    self.upload_file(command, pyversion, filename)
  File "C:\Programming\Python\Anaconda\lib\distutils\command\upload.py", line 73, in upload_file
    raise AssertionError("unsupported schema " + schema)
```

Since `python setup.py register -r pypitest` is no longer needed to upload the package, I run this command: `python setup.py sdist upload -r pypitest`, and the error comes in after I type in my password for pypitest

Here is how my `setup.py` and `.pypirc` files looks like.

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
      name='instapi',
      packages=['instapi'],
      version='0.1',
      description='Clean and simple Instagram API for Python 3.x',
      url='https://github.com/SemptraStar/instapi',
      download_url = 'https://github.com/SemptraStar/instapi/archive/v._0.1.tar.gz',
      author= #me,
      author_email= #also me,
)
```

.pypirc

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
  pypi
  pypitest

[pypi]
repository=https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username= # username
password= # password

[pypitest]
repository=https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username= # username
password= # password
```

**UPDATE 1**

I changed repository URL's to `https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/` for pypi and `https://test.pypi.org/legacy/` for pypitest. Also updated setuptools for the latest version (36.3.0). Nothing changed.

Answer (score 25):

Adding `.pypirc` file also in home directory `C:\Users\<username>`, except from the root of the project, worked for me.

Comment: First I ignored this, but then decided to try - it really solved the issue! Thanks!

Comment: Works for me, for MacOS the path should be ~/.pypirc

Answer (score 7):

What you need to do is use twine. Make sure the version is 1.8+

1. Install it via `pip install twine`
2. Make sure your .pypirc file has the correct credentials for test.pypi.org because that is a separate database from production pypi.
3. Build your sdist `python setup.py sdist`.
4. Use `twine upload --repository pypitest dist/*` for your test upload.
5. Use `twine upload --repository pypi dist/*` for your production upload.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and solved it by specifying where the .pypirc file is located. Per default, it is expected in ~./, but you might want to have it stored in your project.

This issue helped me here:
[Custom location for .pypirc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845125/custom-location-for-pypirc-file)

Answer (score 0):

I was having some trouble with those before as well, though I can't recall if it's the same exactly issue you are describing.  The old URLs should redirect to the new, but PyPi has moved so there's a chance these won't always work.

Try this for pypi server:

```
https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

And this one for pypitest:

```
https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
```

Comment: It seems to be complaining about your URL, so I would focus on that.  For some reason or another, it thinks you put in an invalid URL(specifically that it wasn't `http` or `https`.  Try copying and pasting my URLs directly, with the slash on the end.  Also make sure setuptools and everything are fully up to date.

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#uploading-your-package-to-pypi) of setuptools says

> #### Uploading your package to PyPI
>
> After generating the distribution files, the next step would be to upload your distribution so others can use it. This functionality is provided by twine and is documented in the Python packaging tutorial.

So I suppose no point in trying to debug setuptools upload issues. Build using setuptools and upload using twine.