# Can I have a virtualenv specific .pypirc file?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, setuptools

Pip lets it's config file (pip.ini or pip.conf) live inside the virtualenv. That's neat if you want to make your package resolution different in a specific environment.

But what about the .pypirc file? This normally lives in ${HOME}/.pypirc or %USERPROFILE%.pypirc (on Windows). If you try to create a .pypirc file in the virtualenv's directory it doesnt' seem to be recognized.

Is there a way to specify an alternative location for this file? For example, can I put it in a virtualenv or specify an alternative location with an environment variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom location for .pypirc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845125/custom-location-for-pypirc-file)

Comment: Nothing changed since the time, the fixed location is [still fixed](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/118edbb2b715c96620b51018c1d28e81f2318053/setuptools/package_index.py#L1026).

Answer (score 1):

For a virtual environment `.env`, specify its' path with the parameter `--config-file` as:

```
python -m twine upload --config-file .env/.pypirc dist/*
```